# Recommendation on a Restful client

Tags: rest, restful-url, http-method

I'm developing a web service which has some non standard http methods (CREATE, BEGIN, NEXT).

Up until now I've been using the chrome plugin 'advanced rest client'.  They've just updated it and removed the functionality to select custom method names, something which I'm now finding in all of the rest clients I've found.  Can anyone recommend one that will allow me to type custom method names?

I know I can use cUrl, but ideally I'm looking for something visual.

Comment: Knowing nothing about your system, I nevertheless feel obliged to point out that custom verbs are probably not a good idea, and you should strongly consider the trade-offs before employing them. For example, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/193826/218552.

Comment: What I don't understand about this is; the verbs don't seem to apply to the type of transactions that we are doing.  E.g your transaction is going through multiple consecutive states, with each http call you are adding more info to it, or pushing it along further.  It seem more complicated to have a 'POST' for each stage rather than a method associated with each.

Comment: I don't think anybody's going to be able to help you redesign the system without a lot more information. :-( In general, a system adhering to the principles of REST would either have each state be a resource, or have the client change a state property of the resource and let the back end detect that and do what it needs to.'